# Angular 2 passing value from service to component

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Function inside service:

```js
getUserInfo() {
  this.af.authState.subscribe(authData => {
    let email = authData.email;
    let array = this.database.list('registeredUsers', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'email',
        equalTo: email
      }
    }).subscribe(data => {
      let userFName = data[0].firstName;
    });
  });
}
```

Component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.afService.getUserInfo();
}
```

The function itself works great, but how do I pass the `let userFName` variable to be used within the component?

Comment: How did you double subscribe an Observable?

Comment: @omeralper he didn't? the first subscribe is the authState, the second is the database.list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it sounds like you want is to make this an Injectable service. That will let you make calls into it from any Component.

It looks best to create a new promise to return, which you can resolve once the database.list call is resolved.

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService() {
  public userFName;

  getUserInfo() {
    // return a new promise, which you resolve once you get the data
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.af.authState.subscribe(authData => {
        let email = authData.email;
        let array = this.database.list('registeredUsers', {
          query: {
            orderByChild: 'email',
            equalTo: email
          }
        }).subscribe(data => {
          let userFName = data[0].firstName;

          // resolve promise with username
          resolve(userFName);
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

and your component

```js
@Component({
    providers: [MyService]
  )
}
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    myService.getUserInfo().then(userFName => {
      console.log('userFName =', userFName);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'subscription' on the .subscribe in the component.

Comment: Oops didn't realize it was a nested promise, fixed so that your getUserInfo function returns a new Promise, which you can resolve once the inner database.list call is finished.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `@angular/http` your http requests should return `rxjs/Observable`. And once you subscribe it, it returns subscription. You cannot resubscribe the subscription class.

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
@Injectable()
export class MyService() {

    public userFName;
    getUserInfoPromise():Observable<MyResponseType> {
        let someObservable = this.someApi.someRequestPOST(request).mergeMap((response:MyResponsType) => {
         //you can process the response data here before components use it
              this.userFName = response.userFName;
              return new Promise(resolve => resolve(response));
         });
         return someObservable;
    }
}
```

And in your component, just join the subscription chain in this way.

```
 this.myService
            .getUserInfoPromise(requestData)
            .subscribe(
                (res: MyResponseType) => {

                }, (error) => {

                });
```